# how can i know Items in Tasks list viewed by user(something like "Last Viewed" and "Last Viewed By")?

Tags: list-view, column, event-handlers, tasks, list-item

for every list-item in Lists we have two columns or fields by the name of "Modified" and "Modified By". you got the idea, i wanna have two columns or fields for Tasks List by the name of "Viewed" and "Viewed By".
it shouldn't have to be column or field i just wanna know Last Viewed and who viewed the list item on Tasks list or any other Lists in SharePoint 2010.
how can i reach to this approach?

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint doesn't have OOTB mechanism for capturing 'Item is displayed' except auditing. Using auditing (as Rob pointed in his answer) is way to complicated. I never implemented similar solution so I will agree: In theory it is possible.

One other option is to build custom display page (application page), attach it to your list (content type) as default display form and then utilize OnLoad function to write your data (current user and time) in custom "Viewed" and "Viewed by" fields. But this is not simple and it opens a whole different set of problems (e.g. keeping same look and feel as original DispForm).

I succesfully implemented similar solutions in several occasions but in your case I doubt that it is worthwhile.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a custom field type for this.

see LastViewedFieldType at..

http://lvft.codeplex.com

Comment: While  this may theoretically answer the question, we prefer inclusion of the  essential parts of the answer here, and to provide the link for  reference (in this case to get the actual code). See [answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for general guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer this with some theory because there is no way to do this natively with SharePoint.

The best you can do OOB is turn on auditing for the list and capture list item views.  That data is not something you can surface as a column unless you wrote some code...and here's where the theory comes in.  You could write a custom SPField that mines the audit data for an item and displays the last view entry.  Never done this myself, but in theory it's possible.  Whether or not it would be a good idea (i.e. not sure how well it would perform) is another question.